# Hibernate List key doesn't have a default value

Tags: hibernate, list

i have some trouble with hibernate. I would like to store a list of Transaction objects within a CollaborateableImpl object.

So my hibernate configuration file for CollaborateableImpl looks like this:

```
<class name="CollaborateableImpl" table="Collaborateable">
<id name="id" type="int" column="id">
    <generator class="increment" />
</id>

<property name="name" column="name" type="string" not-null="true" />
<property name="keywords" column="keywords" type="string"/>

<!--  Transactions -->
<list name="transactions" table="Transaction" lazy="false" cascade="all"  fetch="select">
    <key>
        <column name="Collaborateable_id" />
   </key>
   <index column="idx"/>
   <one-to-many class="TransactionImpl" />

</list>
</class>
```

My Transaction config file:

```
<class name="TransactionImpl" table="Transaction">
<id name="id" type="string" column="id">
    <!-- Generator is not needed, since the id is generated with uuid on client -->
</id>

<map name="vectorClock" table="VectorClockEntry" cascade="delete">
    <key column="Transaction_id" />
    <map-key column="User_id" type="int" />
    <element column="value" type="long" />
</map>
</class>
```

So I create a CollaborateableImpl object, store this object with session.save(collaborateableImpl). Everything works fine.
So now I want to add a TransactionImpl object to the list of Transaction of the collaborateImpl object.

```
TransactionImpl t = new TransactionImpl();
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            collaborateableImpl.addTransaction(t);
            session.update(c);
        tx.commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
```

Unfortunately an Exception is thrown:
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'Collaborateable_id' doesn't have a default value

I understand, what hibernate is trying to say, but I have no idea how to solve this problem.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I need to define a  Tag in the Transaction config file:

```
<many-to-one name="collaborateable" class="CollaborateableImpl" fetch="select">
        <column name="Collaborateable_id" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```